# Null response from restshap by asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, restsharp

I've developed with Visual Studio 2019 a ConsoleApp C# where a make a request with restsharp and work good.

here there is the code that I've used for make a request:

```
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;



namespace RetailerUrlStatusChecker
{
    public class Program
    {

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await ProcessRepositories();

        }

        private static async Task ProcessRepositories()
        {


            var client = new RestClient("https://api-developer.com/products");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"category\": \"all\"}", ParameterType.RequestBody);

            var response2 = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync<List>(request);
            List products= response2.Data; 

            //INSERT DATA INTO DB SQL SERVER
            string connectionString = "Data Source=utente-pc\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MYDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=sa";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            try
            {

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO PRODUCT (code, name, description) VALUES (@code, @name, @description)", connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", products.code);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", products.name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", products.description);

                connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            catch
            {
                //Label4.Text = "uh oh";
            }

        }
    }


    public class List
    {

        public string code{ get; set; }
        public string name{ get; set; }
        public string description{ get; set; }
    }






}
```

I need to implement this request in a project web form asp.net, I've try to write the same code but it don't work, I receved a response null.

This is the code about my page asp.net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using RestSharp;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(GetGizmosSvcAsync));
        }

        public async Task GetGizmosSvcAsync()
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://api-developer.com/products");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"category\": \"all\"}", ParameterType.RequestBody);

            var response2 = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync<List>(request);
            List products= response2.Data; 

            //INSERT DATA INTO DB SQL SERVER
            string connectionString = "Data Source=utente-pc\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MYDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=sa";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            try
            {

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO PRODUCT (code, name, description) VALUES (@code, @name, @description)", connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", products.code);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", products.name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", products.description);

                connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            catch
            {
                //Label4.Text = "uh oh";
            }
        }
    }

    public class List
    {

        public string code{ get; set; }
        public string name{ get; set; }
        public string description{ get; set; }
    }

}
```

I've set Async="true" in <%@ page title in my page asp.net

I don't understand why the same code work good on consoleapp c#, but don't work on asp.net c#

Thanks for any help!

The scheme of response is:

```
{
   "code": {
      "type": "string"
    },     
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string"
    }

}
```

UPDATE:

I've read in other forum that there is an incompatibility with the last version of restsharp and framework..
I've understand that the consoleapp use CORE.NET and webapp use FRAMEWORK.NET, and there are some different with component and NuGet.. So I've try to create a webform and install restsharp v106.1.0 and now it work!!!
So all code was ok, the problem was the update restsharp v106.10.1

Thanks to all for help me and I apologize for the trouble.

Comment: Can you add some proper error handling to your catch {} and add any errors to your question.

Comment: I don't have any error. the object response2 is null

Comment: Without knowing what endpoint response structure, its hard to assist you. But based on name ("https://api-developer.com/**products**"), am assuming it returns collection of prodcuts. So, try modifying `var response2 = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync<List>(request);` statement to `var response2 = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync<System.Collections.Generic.List<List>>(request);`

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with your code. Run your API in the debugger and make sure it is returning something when you call it from the web page.

Comment: I've try run API in debugger but don't receve any error, the object response still be null

Comment: There're no differences in compatibility between the latest version of RestSharp within v106 and .NET Core/.NET Framework. RestSharp is built for .NET Framework 4.5.2+ and .NET Standard 2.0+. It is something else. Empty result for typed calls usually mean that you have issues with deserialisation. The easiest way to find it is to use another serialiser, like Newtonsoft.Json. It is all described in the docs.

Comment: I checked the object response before to start deserialisation, and the problem was the object response was empty, so is not a problem of deserialisation... I tried to create a new project webform and I installed RestSharp 106.1.0 than I copied the exact same code and it work... So 2 identical project, same code, same framework, but different versione of RestSharp... v106.10.1 don't work...... v106.1.0 work good.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what endpoint response structure, its hard to assist you. But based on name ("https://api-developer.com/**products**"), am assuming it returns collection of prodcuts. So, try modifying `var response2 = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync<List>(request);` statement to `var response2 = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync<System.Collections.Generic.List<List>>(request);`

**Or** based on your next statement `List products = response2.Data;` am assuming request returns some object which contains Data which is collection of List objects something like below:

```
public class RootObject()
{
    public System.Collections.Generic.List<List> Data { get; set; }
}
```

If that is the case, then try modifying `var response2 = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync<List>(request);` to `var response2 = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync<RootObject>(request);`

So, your final `GetGizmosSvcAsync` method looks like below:

```
public async Task GetGizmosSvcAsync()
{
    var client = new RestClient("https://api-developer.com/products");
    client.Timeout = -1;
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"category\": \"all\"}", ParameterType.RequestBody);

    var response2 = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync<RootObject>(request);
    var products = response2.Data;  //List products = response2.Data; 

    //INSERT DATA INTO DB SQL SERVER
    string connectionString = "Data Source=utente-pc\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MYDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=sa";
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    try
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO PRODUCT (code, name, description) VALUES (@code, @name, @description)", connection);
        connection.Open();

        foreach (var product in products)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", product.code);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", product.name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", product.description);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    catch
    {
        //Label4.Text = "uh oh";
    }
}
```

Comment: the request return the scheme like my class <List> { code, name, description} I've try to change response 2 with your suggestion but still don't work... The same code in ConsoleApp C# work, don't work only in webform asp.net...

Comment: can you run the same request in fiddler or postman instead of console app? if you are able to execute it via fiddler, then I would compare this with the request that is going out when you debug web app.

Comment: I've tested with postman and I've compare the request with the request of consoleapp and are the same, than I've compare the request with web app and also are the same... Is a real mystery

Comment: Can you check if I wrong to use async in webapp? I've try to look on google and I found many different types for make a reequest async...

Comment: Its correct. Two things: Not sure how its working in console app because based on your update response scheme does not match object of type List. code, name and description are again objects but not string as specified in List. Also, in I found this on http://restsharp.org/: **It is recommended to use AddJsonBody or AddXmlBody methods instead of AddParameter with type BodyParameter. Those methods will set the proper request type and do the serialization work for you.**. Also, leave fiddler open when you are running web app so, fiddler captures and shows this request from webapp.

Comment: Sorry, the scheme that I've posted was wrong.. now is correct... I've try to change request.addParameter; to request.AddJsonBody(postData); but have the same result... In consoleapp work good, in webapplication don't work... If I run line to line code I've see that in console app after line var response2 = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync<List>(request); I wait 3 or 4 second before run next line, instead in webform It run quick the next line..

Comment: still your response scheme does not match with class List structure. Also, can you try sync calls instead of async (just to isolate the doubt that you are having with async). If that works with existing class List, then as you suspected it could be issue with async.